# How to insert duplicate value depending on what value was entered using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to summarize it on my title but let me explain you what I am trying accomplish in more details below.

Currently I pass an array to my query and use a foreach to insert each array in to my db as shown below.

```
if(is_array($myArr)){
 foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email) values ('$userID', '$email')";
  mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
 }
}
```

Currently my array looks the following

```
Array
(
[39] => sessa@test.com
[54] => sessa@test.com
[55] => sessa@test.com
[56] => sessa@test.com
[57] => mark@foo.com
[58] => mark@foo.com
[59] => mark@foo.com
[60] => mark@foo.com
[61] => sam@bar.com
[62] => sam@bar.com
[63] => sam@bar.com
[64] => sam@bar.com
)
```

with the '$userID' being [39] and 'email' being the..well email.

This is where my question comes in.

What I want to achieve is insert a new id in a new column in I have called 'url' in this 'url' column I want to be able to increment by 1 and add the same value to the row with the same email.

So something like this.

```
UserID |    email        | url  
===============================
  39   |  sessa@test.com |  1   
  54   | sessa@test.com  |  1  
  55   | sessa@test.com  |  1  
  56   | sessa@test.com  |  1  
  57   | mark@foo.com    |  2  
  58   | mark@foo.com    |  2  
  59   | mark@foo.com    |  2   
  60   | mark@foo.com    |  2  
  61   | sam@bar.com     |  3  
  62   | sam@bar.com     |  3  
  63   | sam@bar.com     |  3  
  64   | sam@bar.com     |  3
```

I'm hoping this makes sense. Thank you for reading. Always appreciate the help.

Comment: This smells like a need for a table with `id, email` (in which id holds the autoincrement column), and a table with `userId,url`?

Comment: @Wrikken Hi Wrikken I have simplified the table for this question. Thanks for you input :)

Comment: That does not mean it still doesn't smell like some normalization could be healthy, but hey, you're in a better position to judge whether it's needed than I am ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if(is_array($myArr)) : 

foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){

    $emails[] = $email;
}

$emails = array_unique($emails);

foreach($emails as $e){
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){

        if($email == $e){

            $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('$userID', '$email','$counter')";
            $counter++;
        }
    }

}

endif;
```

You could create one SQL statement for all the insert by using this.

```
   if(is_array($myArr)) : 

    foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){

        $emails[] = $email;
    }

    $emails = array_unique($emails);
    $sql = '';
            $counter = 1;
    foreach($emails as $e){

        foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){

            if($email == $e){

                $sql .= "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('$userID', '$email','$counter');";

            }
        }
        $counter++;
    }

    endif;

    mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
```

SQL output

```
        INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('39', 'sessa@test.com','1');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('54', 'sessa@test.com','1');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('55', 'sessa@test.com','1');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('56', 'sessa@test.com','1');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('57', 'mark@foo.com','2');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('58', 'mark@foo.com','2');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('59', 'mark@foo.com','2');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('60', 'mark@foo.com','2');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('61', 'sam@bar.com','3');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('62', 'sam@bar.com','3');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('63', 'sam@bar.com','3');INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('64', 'sam@bar.com','3');
```

Comment: Well, you can actually only run one query at a time with `mysql_query()`

Comment: Yes this is my second solution .. and the best.. why hitting the db many times while you can create 1 query.

Comment: what he meant; from manual `mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier. `

Comment: well `mysql_query` is an old method to access the database why he don't use PDO ? that's the question

Answer (score 4):

I would go for ON DUPLICATE KEY;

Make sure you have an unique index on email.

```
if(is_array($myArr)){
 foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email) values ('$userID', '$email') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=url+1";
  mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
 }
}
```

Edit:

OK, this might be the solution:

```
$data = array();
$ids = 1;

if(is_array($myArr)){
    foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){

       $domain = substr(strstr($email,"@"),1);

        if (! isset($data[$domain]))
        {
            $data[$domain] = $ids;
            $ids ++;
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) 
                VALUES ('$userID', '$email','".$data[$domain]."')";
        mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing .. but he wants the + after a new email comes up. doesn't this increment url for each email ? so email 1 - 1234 then email 2 1234

Comment: @John Hi John, your second solution seems to be incrementing the url id with the same email.

Comment: @BaconJuice I updated my answer. I did not understand the question. You wanted an ID fo each domainname in the emailaddress? My code should work now.

Comment: @John no, its not domain specific. I have it outlined on my question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize it by 1 query.

```
if(is_array($myArr)){
 foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `userdata` (`userID`, `email`, `url`) 
         select '$userID', '$email', count(`email`) +1 from `userdata` where `email` = '$email'";
  mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory - you can create one more array data strcture and store the emails and ID..

For e.g. You can do something like this in your for loop...

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;

if(is_array($myArr)){
    foreach($myArr as $userID=> $email){
        $url_id = '';

        if (! isset($data[$email]))
        {
            $data[$email] = ++$i;
        }

        $url_id  = $data[$email];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO userdata (userID, email,url) values ('$userID', '$email','$url_id')";
        mysql_query($sql) or exit(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I don't think it's most efficient solution.. but it should work..